# I can't open the connection to the local database

Tags: c#, database-connection, sql-server-ce

I get an exception error for my code. Please help me - what is the problem? (I'm new to this :/)

My database is local database.

```
SqlConnection myconnection;

private void insertBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        myconnection = new SqlConnection();
        myconnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Saeed\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\dictionary1\\dictionary1\\Database1.sdf";
        myconnection.Open();
        //string query = "INSERT INTO dictionary (id,enWord,faWord) VALUES (4,'pen','خودكار')";
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection);
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Here is the exception error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Your connection string does not look right... That could be the issue..

Comment: A SQL Server CE database (`.sdf` file) requires use of `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` - not `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` ....

Comment: thankyou , but i dont have SqlCeConnection! how i can add this class?!

Comment: go to msdn and see how connection string look like. I think you made mistake on connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are accessing a SQL Server Compact Database `.sdf` file, you will want to use the [`SqlCeConnection`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwisma_Rj5vMAhWhsIMKHRxXDz0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection(v%3Dvs.100).aspx&usg=AFQjCNH-bAw0H9N_B7l_b1X4mBZABLo5RA&sig2=L-VEAt2K6ewSbaDkwQva0g&bvm=bv.119745492,d.amc) and [`SqlCeCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand(v=vs.100).aspx) classes as opposed to the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` classes, which you would use for traditional SQL Server connections.

Additionally, you can try using the `Persist Security Info=False;` setting within your connection string using an example similar to [the ones mentioned on ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/) using

```
private void insertBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Open your connection
    using(var myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Saeed\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\dictionary1\dictionary1\Database1.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"))
    {
         // Build your query
         var query = "INSERT INTO dictionary (id,enWord,faWord) VALUES (4,'pen','خودكار')"
         // Build a command to execute
         using(var myCommand = new SqlCeCommand(query,myConnection))
         {
               // Open your connection
               myConnection.Open();
               // Execute your query
               myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou , but i dont have SqlCeConnection! how i can add this class?!

Comment: should i use service based database?! :p

Comment: You should be able to add a reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe` in your project. If you don't have these you can try installing the [SQL Server Compact Design Tools here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709). It's worth considering that [SQL Compact is deprecated](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776328/port-sql-compact-to-windows-rt#ctl00_MasterBody_upCommunityComments) in favor of [LocalDB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/).

Comment: sorry i ask again , if it will be deprecated what should i use instead. i want to code small apps that run on local pc! doesnt need server. :p

Comment: It depends on which version of Visual Studio you are using. Most newer editions of the IDE will use `LocalDB` out of the box when you create new applications (using the default scaffolding) and have utilities for creating the databases as well.

Answer (score -1):

Your connection string is incorrect. It needs to look something like this:

> "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial
>   Catalog=**YOUR_DATABASE_NAME**;server=(local)"

See here for more information on connection strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx